# Firefox user.js is not getting copied to profiles even though it is available under browser/defaults/profile

Tags: firefox, mozilla

user.js is not getting copied to profile folder automatically. I have a file user.js in installed directory/browser/defaults/profile/user.js in version Mozilla Firefox 52.0.2

The same operation used to happen in Mozilla Firefox 45.5.1 without any problem

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by following the below link..

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig